# syntax error in net user command while changing password

Tags: cmd

I am trying to change my password through net user command using command prompt(administrator).

When i type `net user Taimoor Ali mypassword` and press enter, it says:

> syntax of this command is: " NET USER [username [password |
>   *][options]][DOMAIN] "

along with other syntax examples.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?
I am able to log in through my finger print scan but forgot my password.

Comment: Try taking your user name in quotes, like this: `net user "Taimoor Ali" mypassword`.

Comment: It worked like wonder. Thankyou for your input, i was trying to do it with braces and paranthesis instead quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Since your user name contains a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, which constitutes a token separator in Windows `cmd` (like also <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=`, and the non-break space, code `0xFF`), your `net user` command line receives actually three tokens: `Taimoor` (user name), `Ali` (password) and `mypassword` (additional unexpected token).

To fix that, use quotation marks:

```cmd
net user "Taimoor Ali" mypassword
```

Or, in case the password also contains token separators:

```cmd
net user "Taimoor Ali" "mypassword"
```

There are also other characters that have got special meanings to `cmd`, which can also be taken as literal characters if the string is surrounded by quotation marks: `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `|` and `!`.